# Searching in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jssc

I'm creating "hello world" Maven Java project in Eclipse. I'm planing to include [java-simple-serial-connector](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) module. According to my understanding I need 3 things in order to add library to maven project:

```
Group Id
Artifact Id
Version
```

Please, correct if I'm wrong.

I do search in https://search.maven.org for `jssc` and got list of projects :
[image]

How to know which one is right? Why version `2.8.0` in `org.scream3r` is updated `12-Mar-2014`  while `org.everit.osgi.bundles` is updated on `30-Jan-2017`?
How to know which one is official?

Comment: How should I know cause you want to use that library so you have to make the choice which one to use... The dates are simply different cause these are two different libraries and they have been released by different people and at different times...What do you mean by `official`?

Answer (score 1):

The link that you shared i.e [java-simple-serial-connector](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) it selfs says that

`All new downloads will be available on GitHub: https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector/releases'>https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector/releases`

and so you will want to use the `org.scream3r` one.

Answer (score 1):

By searching https://mvnrepository.com for java-simple-serial-connector you get your desired dependency in version 2.8.0:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc

Click on the version number and simply copy the xml code from the website into your pom.xml.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the maven repo for the latest.
Check this.

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc/2.8.0

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
    <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```